# Can I make Brackets/Edge Code CC highlight a .ssi file as if it were an HTML file?

Tags: ssi, adobe-edge, adobe-brackets

My .SSI file in Adobe Edge Code CC is treated as plaintext as you can see from this image:
[image: Screenshot of Adobe Edge Code displaying a .ssi file]

I would like it to syntax highlight as per a .html file. I have tried the extensions registry at: https://brackets-registry.aboutweb.com/ and cannot find anything appropriate. Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I found the answer, which is to edit languages.json as per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21592200/238230

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** this is now much easier to do:

1. Open the .ssi file
2. In the status bar (lower-right), click the dropdown that says "Text"
3. Choose a different option (HTML in this case)
4. Open the dropdown again and choose the "Set as Default" option at the top

---

*Original answer:*

You don't have to clone Brackets from git as suggested in the other SO answer - it was only needed because the file extension in that case was already assigned to a different language (which isn't that common).

For unassigned file extensions like .ssi, you can create a very simple Brackets extension - just a main.js file containing this code:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var LanguageManager = brackets.getModule("language/LanguageManager");
    var language = LanguageManager.getLanguage("html");
    language.addFileExtension("ssi");
});
```

This is easier to set up than pulling from git, and a little more foolproof.  (In the future, this should be more even easily configurable though).

For more info, see this answer: [how to add file extension in adobe-brackets editor ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753792/how-to-add-file-extension-in-adobe-brackets-editor/21867052#21867052)